# How to get tables of data from JupyterLab to Excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I am completely new to JupyterLab and python in general so I am looking for some help today. Specifically, I am interested in getting data from JuypterLab into Excel. The data I have in JL are tables that I have pulled from the internet, using the pandas function as shown in the link below. My next step that I am having trouble with is how to pull those data tables from JL to Excel. Is there a 'Get Data' function that is best for this or would it be easier using python to accomplish this task? Ideally, I want to be able to do this for a large set of data/tables that I scrape from the internet.

I'm starting using the answer to a question I asked previously: [Web scraping multiple tables from a single webpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72705462/web-scraping-multiple-tables-from-a-single-webpage)

```
import pandas as pd
df =pd.read_html('https://www.basketball-reference.com/international/players/roko-prkacin-1.html')[0:4]
print(df)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a pandas dataframe getting it into excel-format is very easy:

```
df.to_excel("filename.xlsx")
```

see also the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html

To get meaningfull dataframes from html is something different.

Comment: Thanks! How much more of a project is it to pull multiple pandas dataframes into a single (or several) Excel workbook?

Comment: By providing the parameter "sheet_name" you can write the dataframes to different excel sheets:  df.to_excel("filename.xlsx", sheet_name="sheet1") than write the next dataframe to another sheet. df2.to_excel("filename.xlsx", sheet_name="sheet2"